# Programming exercise specification

Tags: java, input, io, stdin

As part of a programming exercise I received the following:

"Simulator will receive orders from stdin in a simplified ascii format specified later in this document..."

"Input is received from stdin, and is in comma-separated ascii format. You may assume that the input will always be correctly formatted"

Example:

B,100322,5103,7500

This is all about the input mechnism. What i don't understand is the stdin them mention - is that the usual console input by the user, file input etc. ?

Comment: It means "standard input"... In your case this may be console input by the user. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams, for example and links inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual console, yes.

> In Java, the standard streams are referred to by `System.in` (for *stdin*), `System.out` (for *stdout*), and `System.err` (for *stderr*).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams for further details

Answer (score 2):

The stdin is the console `System.in` (if not redefined with `System.setIn(InputStream)`).

Answer (score 2):

I googled `stdin` and the first match was http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams  which states

> The three I/O connections are called standard input (stdin), standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr)

So I googled `stdin java` and the first match was http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.html

Which has

```
// assume Unicode UTF-8 encoding
private static String charsetName = "UTF-8";

// assume language = English, country = US for consistency with System.out.
private static Locale usLocale = new Locale("en", "US");

// the scanner object
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in), charsetName);
```

You can change the charsetName = "ASCII"